# Using Abel test in an integral to show convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $f:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function with the conditions:

1. $x^2f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1]$
2. $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^2 f(x) = 0$
3. $f'(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1]$

Show that $\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(1/x) dx$ is convergent.

While they did not mention the method, I tried change of variable using $u(x) = 1/x$ and then applying Abel test since that seemed to be the most intuitive, but I was unable to conclude anything. Can anyone provide some hint? Thanks!

Comment: (quick suggestion) put u=1/(1-x)